# problem saving date to mysql from asp.net

Tags: c#

I m trying to save the date to *mysql* from *jquery* *DatePicker* from *C#*

```
string datetime = txtDate.Text + " " + time;//05/11/2011 5:30 pm                    

string getSQL1 = 
   "INSERT into tblconcertdetail 
   (Address, City, Pincode, Country, Concert_Date) 
   VALUES ('" + addr + "','" + txtCCity.Text + "','" + txtCpincode.Text + "','" +
   ddlCCountry.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + Convert.DateTime(datetime) + "')";
```

Here `getsql1` shows me the date field filled but in database it stores *0000-00-00 00:00* value.
I m not getting why it is so.

I also try `convert.ToString(datetime)` to.

Comment: Woa. That's prone to SQL injections. Never construct queries by concatenating text together. Use parameters instead.

Comment: Using parameters while preventing SQL injection attacks, also makes the code more readable, at least to me. I could at a glance see the parameters passed, their values, and optionally data types. Here is a good article on parameters. http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/RunanINSERTstatementwithparameters.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you *have to* use parameters for 2 reasons:

1. Prevent SQL Injections.
2. Handle data type conversions. In your case, handling the .NET `DateTime` type to its equivalent value in database.